# Error when trying to send welcome email with Action Mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku

I generated a action mailer from the ruby guide. However, when I try doing a test run on deployed site through Heroku, I get an error saying something went wrong and to check the logs.

I commented out the method that calls for the delivery of the email and sign up works fine. The email is practically a welcome email. I'm not sure where to go from here.

this is from my ActionMailer

```
default from: "from@example.com"

def welcome_email(user)
  @user = user
  @url ='https://inyourshoes.herokuapp.com/signup'
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to InYourShoes!')
 end
end
```

This is from my usercontroller

```
def create
 @user = User.new(user_params)
 if @user.save
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
  sign_in @user 
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to InYourShoes!"
  redirect_to @user  
 else
   render'new'
 end
```

end

Basically,i want a email to be sent once the user successfully signs up on the website. Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you add the smtp settings to production.rb?

Comment: `I'm not sure where to go from here` - How about checking the logs?

Comment: Are you using Ruby 2.0?

Comment: @H-man i placed it in my development, maybe thats why.  do i have to place config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true in there also?

Comment: @BroiSatse i have no idea how to check, i went into my heroku account and in settings it showed nothing

Comment: @pdoherty926 yep! latest version

Comment: @ApprenticeProgrammer - from your repository run `heroku logs`. You needd heroku toolbelt installed, but you should have it anyway already.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Ruby >= 2.0, try:

```
default({from: "from@example.com"})
```

Otherwise:

```
default({ :from => "from@example.com" })
```